# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intendando hacer un item list view con titulos, precios y categoria de gasolina, para que se vea en este item list view.

Soy nuevo en android y no estoy seguro de que podria haber fallado en mi codigo. Mi proyecto logra compilarse y ejecutarse pero al entrar a esa seccion del codigo, tanto en el emulador como el el telefono se crashea la app.

Aqui el codigo.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListadoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // instancia de ListView
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    // inicializar el adaptador y la  fuente de datos
    adaptador = new ProductoArrayAdapter(this,DataSource.PRODUCTOS);

    // relacionado la lista al adaptador
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);


}
}
```

DataSource.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DataSource {
static List PRODUCTOS = new ArrayList<Producto>();

static{
    PRODUCTOS.add(new Producto("Gasolina Magna" , "$10.91", 
R.drawable.ic_magna));
    PRODUCTOS.add(new Producto("Gasolina Premium" , "$12.10", 
R.drawable.ic_premium));
    PRODUCTOS.add(new Producto("Diesel" , "$14.20", R.drawable.ic_diesel));
}
}
```

ProductoArrayAdapter.java
    public class ProductoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public ProductoArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Producto> objects) {super(context,0, objects);}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Obteniendo una instancia de inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Salvando la referencia del view de la fila
    View listItemView = convertView;

    //Comprobando si el Viwe no existe
    if(null == convertView){
        //Si no existe, entonces inflarlo con image_list_view.xml
        listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_item, parent, 
false);
    }

    //Obteniendo instancia de los TextViews
    TextView titulo = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView subtitulo = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    ImageView categoria = (ImageView) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.category);

    //Obteniendo instancia de la Tarea en la posicion actual
    Producto item = getItem(position);

    titulo.setText(item.getNombre());
    subtitulo.setText(item.getPrecio());
    categoria.setImageResource(item.getcategoria());
    //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
    return listItemView;

}
}
```

Producto.java

```
public class Producto {
private String nombre;
private String precio;
private int categoria;

public Producto(String nombre, String precio, int categoria){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.categoria = categoria;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public void setPrecio(String precio){
    this.precio = precio;
}
public void setCategoria(int categoria){this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getNombre(){ return nombre; }
public String getPrecio(){ return precio; }
public int getcategoria(){ return categoria; }



}
```

activity_listado.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lista"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

image_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Mensaje de error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.pablo.gasolinerasbarclin, PID: 16819
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pablo.gasolinerasbarclin/com.example.pablo.gasolinerasbarclin.ListadoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.pablo.gasolinerasbarclin.ListadoActivity.onCreate(ListadoActivity.java:24)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás buscando una referencia de un `id` no existente en el root (`ContentView`) que carga el `Activity`. Por lo tanto te causa:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

En tu caso, tu `Activity` esta cargando `activity_main.axml` como el root principal, pero la referencia o `id` del recurso `ListView` está definida en `activity_listado.axml`.

La solución para este caso es cargar `activity_listado` como el `ContentView` de tu `Activity`:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);`

o definir el `ListView` en `activity_main.axml`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias a esto ya funciono mi programa, creo que se me habia pasado ese detalle y por eso puse activity_main en el ContentView